# MongoDB 2d $near query issue

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I created a dummy collection **locations** with a couple of documents:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("56b1c6c32798710b058b4568"),
  "title": "place1",
  "coords": {
    "lng": -77.0057694,
    "lat": 38.8844788
  }
}

{
  "_id": ObjectId("56b1c8032798710c058b4567"),
  "title": "place2",
  "coords": {
    "lng": -77.042787,
    "lat": 38.926703
  }
}
```

The "coords" field has a **2d** index:

```
/** locations indexes **/
db.getCollection("locations").ensureIndex({
  "coords": "2d"
},[

]);
```

The following query returns 0 results although I expect it to return both documents:

```
{
  "coords": {
    "$near": {
      "lng": -77.023362,
      "lat": 38.901002
    },
    "$maxDistance": 0.002
  }
}
```

The distance between points in both documents is about 6 km whereas the point in the query is in the middle of them, and $maxDistance is about 13 km (13 / 6391 ~= 0.002 radians)

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

MongoDB v. 3.0.1

Answer (score 4):

I noticed your collection documents do not conform to the [legacy format](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-legacy-coordinate-pairs) or the [GeoJSON format](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/#geo-overview-location-data) for geospatial indexes and queries.

When building collections with geospatial data please make sure not to mix the two different formats. I would recommend using GeoJSON formats moving forward:

```
{ "title" : "place1",
    "coords" : { 
        "type" : "Point", 
        "coordinates" : [ -77.0057694, 38.8844788 ] 
               } 
}

{ "title" : "place2", 
    "coords" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ -77.042787, 38.926703 ] 
               }
}
```

After the collection is created we need to create a [2dsphere index](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/) on the coordinates:

```
db.yourCollection.createIndex({coords:"2dsphere"})
```

With the created collection and index we now have to query the dataset with [$nearSphere](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/):

```
db.yourCollection.find({ "coords": { $nearSphere:[-77.023362,38.901002],$maxDistance: 0.002 } })
```

When I run above scenario on my machine this is the output I get:

```
db.yourCollection.find({ "coords": { $nearSphere:[-77.023362,38.901002],$maxDistance: 0.002  } })

{ "_id" : ObjectId("56bd1153439b16ea3a0847ed"), "title" : "place1", "coords" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -77.0057694, 38.8844788 ] } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56bd1249439b16ea3a0847ee"), "title" : "place2", "coords" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -77.042787, 38.926703 ] } }
```

Lastly make sure to use the latest stable release of MongoDB for bug fixes and general enhancements. Currently for v3.0 it is [v3.0.9](https://www.mongodb.org/downloads#previous), and for v3.2 it is [v3.2.1](https://www.mongodb.org/downloads#production)